# How to get "materials" array when I load my JSON file using THREE.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

On an older version of THREE.JS this code worked perfectly fine:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("ns.js", function(geometry){

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(geometry.materials));

                mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 0.05;
                scene.add(mesh);

                loadRestOfScene();
            });
```

But in a new version "geometry" doesn't have a materials property. How do I get that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern to follow in your case:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( 'model.js', function ( geometry, materials ) {

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,  new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );

    scene.add( mesh );

} );
```

three.js r.63

Comment: Tnx! That's exactly what I needed.